# Problem in sharpness of Heaviside Function

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method, discontinuity

The Heaviside function is not sharp, Do not know why?

```
ss=NDSolve[{D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], x, x], 
u[x, 0] == HeavisideTheta[x - 1] HeavisideTheta[2 - x] , 
u[0, t] == 0, u[Pi, t] == 0}, u, {x, 0, Pi}, {t, 0, 3}]
Plot[u[x, t] /. ss /. t -> 0, {x, 0, Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Discretization and interpolation.

Comment: Then how can I invoke sharp Heaviside function in the NDSolve?

Comment: Similar to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/169461/12558) post.

Comment: The more serious problem is, one i.c. `Derivative[0,1][u][x,0]=…` is missing.

Comment: @xzczd Can you suggest me how to remove the hard oscillation, in NDSolve my solution is oscillating around zero that I don't want, I am using working precision-> 50, it is taking huge time. Is there any method to increase the precision of NDSolve arbitrary?

Comment: As mentioned in my last comment, you need one more initial condition `Derivative[0,1][u][x,0]==…` to form a initial-boundary value problem. Currently given the missing of initial condition, `NDSolve` has automatically used a zero `NeumannValue` at `t==3` (in this case it's equivalent to `Derivative[0,1][u][x,3]==0`) to form a boundary value problem, which is a typical [ill-posed problem](http://www.math.nsc.ru/LBRT/u2/Survey%20paper.pdf).

Comment: The same Equation I can solve analytically with these initial conditions, it is the basic well-known diffusion equation, Moreover I tried to include this Derivative condition, still it gives me error.

Comment: Infact at t=0 the dynamics equation does not matter, it should replicate the initial conditions as it is,it must be the sharp heaviside function, there is a problem of interpolation by NDSolve, i want to handle the tolerance limit of NDSolve if you can help.

Comment: No, you're not solving diffusion equation. If what you're trying to solve is diffussion equation, then you've made a simple mistake: the left hand side should be `D[u[x, t], t]` rather than `D[u[x, t], t, t]`.

Answer (score 12):

In `NDSolve` you can only approximate a discontinuity in the spatial domain by interpolation over a discrete set.  In [FEM](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOverview.html), this is the only option and the order of interpolation is restricted to 1 or 2.  In [the method of lines](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html), the time integration may have discontinuities (even if the spatial discretization is done by FEM).

My suggestion is that one can improve the approximation of `HeavisideTheta` by refining the mesh near `x == 1, 2`, `t == 0`.  One issue is that `HeavisideTheta[0.]` is undefined, and therefore `x == 1., 2.` should be avoided.  This is better dealt with by substituting a function for it that is defined everywhere, such as

```
HeavisideTheta -> UnitStep              (* asymmetric *) 
HeavisideTheta -> (1 - UnitStep[-#] &)  (* asymmetric *) 
HeavisideTheta -> (1/2 + Sign[#]/2 &)   (* symmetric *)
```

The question is what value to assign `HeavisideTheta[0]`: `1`, `0`, `1/2`, etc.  The first two are asymmetrical and would result in the sorts of parabolas seen in the OP (if using order 2 interpolation).  The value `1/2` would yield a symmetrical result if the grid points were symmetrically placed about the discontinuity.  It would result in a straight, steep, but not vertical, line.

Here is one way to construct the symmetrical solution:

```
Needs@"NDSolve`FEM`";
With[{dx = 10^-3}, 
 bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> {{0, 0}, {1 - dx, 0}, {1 + dx, 0},
     {2 - dx, 0}, {2 + dx, 0}, {Pi, 0}, {Pi, 3}, {0, 3}},
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[Partition[Range@8, 2, 1, 1]]},
   "MeshOrder" -> 2]
 ]

emesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01]
emesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Block[{HeavisideTheta = 1/2 + Sign[#]/2 &},
 ss = NDSolve[{D[u[x, t], t, t] == D[u[x, t], x, x], 
    u[x, 0] == HeavisideTheta[x - 1] HeavisideTheta[2 - x], 
    u[0, t] == 0, u[Pi, t] == 0}, u, {x, t} ∈ emesh]
 ]

Plot[u[x, t] /. ss /. t -> 0., {x, 0, Pi}, MaxRecursion -> 15]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A close-up look reveals the lines are not vertical:

```
Plot[u[x, t] /. ss /. t -> 0., {x, 0.99, 1.01}, MaxRecursion -> 15]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The quality of the solution to the whole PDE seems pretty poor, but that is a separate question.

Comment: Thank you so much, but after adding this emesh, this step function should spread 
at  the subsequent time for Diffusion equation, but   /t->1 is not giving the correct behavior

Comment: @SachinKaushik That's what my last sentence meant to hint at, that there's a problem with the mathematics/numerics.  See @ andre's answer and @ xzczd's comment. You can combine my trick with method of lines: Use `With[{dx = 10.^-3}, With[{c = List /@ Union[Subdivide[0., Pi, 100], {1 - dx, 1 + dx, 2 - dx, 2 + dx}]}, emesh = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> c, "MeshElements" -> {LineElement[Partition[Range@Length@c, 2, 1]]}, "MeshOrder" -> 2] ]]` and specify `{x} \[Element] emesh` instead of `{x, 0, Pi}` in Andre's code, but it still looks wrong.

Comment: the solution you provided is working fine. while editing you make it a wave equation whereas initial conditions and boundary conditions are suitable for diffusion equation (heat equation) and I am finding quality of solution is also good. Only problem is if I add  u[x,t] (x-Integrate[x u[x,t],{x,0,Xmax}]) to the diffusion equation in your code with emesh then it shows error, this error is not present if we simply use NDSolve without emesh, however then there is issue of the sharpness of Heaviside function. If you can suggest something how can I invoke this in your code?

Comment: your code is good as long as I have linear equation, for any non linearity it does not work.

Comment: @SachinKaushik FEM is implemented for linear equations only. For nonlinear, `NDSolve` can offer only the method of lines, which requires a regular grid (or a Chebyshev grid for `"Pseudospectral"`). That will give you an asymmetric situation leading to a slight overshoot like for your original code, unless you move the unit bump to points that happen to land symmetrically between the regular grid points. With a fine grid spacing, it should still give an decent approximation to the IC, imo.

Answer (score 6):

This is not a answer, only some investigations that are worth to be shared.

Here is the code of the OP, exactly :

```
ss=NDSolve[{D[u[x, t], t, t] == D[u[x, t], x, x], 
u[x, 0] == HeavisideTheta[x - 1] HeavisideTheta[2 - x] , 
u[0, t] == 0, u[Pi, t] == 0}, u, {x, 0, Pi}, {t, 0, 3}]
Plot[u[x, t] /. ss /. t -> 0, {x, 0, Pi}]
```

The aim of the following approach is to discover :

- the method used by `NDSolve`

So far I know there are 3 possibilites :

1) Method of Lines + Tensor Product Grid

2) Method of Lines + Finite Element Method

3) Finite Element Method for all the independent variables, including  what is generally considered as time (here t) and is treated with the Method of Lines.

- What is the real mesh used by FEM. Is it responsible of the problem of the OP (answer : Yes)

extraction of the interpolatingFunction :

```
ssFunction=ss[[1,1,2]]
```

[image]

**First question : Was FEM used ?**

This subject is discuted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140773/5467)

```
ssFunction["ElementMesh"]
```

> ElementMesh[{{0., 3.14159}, {0., 3.}}, {QuadElement["<" 420 ">"]}]

So FEM was used.

**Second Question : Was it a purely finite element method or was the temporal variable treated with the Method of Lines ?**

The following code permits to have the answer. It comes from the documentation "finite element Programming":

```
{state}=NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{D[u[x, t], t, t] == D[u[x, t], x, x], 
u[x, 0] == HeavisideTheta[x - 1] HeavisideTheta[2 - x] , 
u[0, t] == 0, u[Pi, t] == 0}, u, {x, 0, Pi}, {t, 0, 3}]
```

> {NDSolve`StateData["<" "SteadyState" ">"]}

"SteadyState" indicates that there no temporal variable. If `t` were considered as a temporal variable, then the code above would have returned :

> {NDSolve`StateData["<" 0. ">"]}

**What is the Mesh used by FEM ?**

Since the problem is treated without special consideration for the variable `t`, the mesh is of dimension 2.
In fact we are mainly interested in the spacial grid at time t=0.

To analyse this, I propose to change the problem from kind 3) to kind 2). (that has the problem of the OP, I mean the bumps, too).
Here is the new code :

```
ssValue=NDSolve[{D[u[x, t], t, t] == D[u[x, t], x, x], 
u[x, 0] == HeavisideTheta[x - 1] HeavisideTheta[2 - x] , 
(D[u[x, t],t] /. t -> 0) == 0,
u[0, t] == 0, u[Pi, t] == 0}, u, {x, 0, Pi}, {t, 0, 3},
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines",
                    "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
                    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement","MeshOptions"-> 
                  {"MaxCellMeasure"-> 3. 10^-1}}}]

ssValueFunction=ssValue[[1,1,2]]
```

Note that I have added `(D[u[x, t],t] /. t -> 0) == 0` in your code. This is necessary for the wave equation : [see here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/141835/5467).
I'm surprised that you can obtain an answer with your code.

Now, one can retrieve the mesh and the coordinates :

```
Point00=Point[ssValueFunction["ElementMesh"] ["Coordinates"] //
(First /@ # &) //
({#,ssValueFunction[#,0]}& /@ # &)]
```

Finally, a plot explains what happens in the OP's question :

```
Plot[ ssValueFunction[x,0.], {x, 0, Pi},Mesh-> All,ImageSize->900,AspectRatio->0.2,
Epilog-> {AbsolutePointSize[8],Red,Point00}]
```

[image]

The red points are the points of the mesh used by the FEM.
It's the interpolation  in the function returned by `NDSolve` that is the origin of the bumps.

Comment: "I'm surprised that you can obtain an answer with your code. " Not that surprising, because `"FiniteElement"` method has used zero `NeumannValue` for `t==3` and solved the BVP of wave equation, which is a typical [ill-posed problem](http://www.math.nsc.ru/LBRT/u2/Survey%20paper.pdf).